Python multiprocessing pool with class objects
This code is runnable
I get an empty array "link"
although I should get an array with objects in it,
when I print link in func_b it is not empty
Self should refer to the object, but I guess this is not the case with multiprocessing, it seems to be some kind of copy
Does anyone know a solution ?
THX
class class_b:
     
     def __init__(self):
          
        self.counter=0
        self.sum=[]

class class_a:

    import random as ran
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import os

    def __init__(self):

        self.link=[0]*50
        self.arr_a=[0]*100

    def func_b(self,arg):
        
        arr_key=self.ran.randint(0, 50)

        if self.link[arr_key] ==0:

            self.link[arr_key]=class_b()

        else:

            obj=self.link[arr_key]
            obj.counter+=1
            (obj.sum).append(self.ran.randint(0,10))
        
        print(self.link)

        

    def func_a(self):
        
        with self.Pool(processes=self.os.cpu_count()) as pool:

                pool.map(self.func_b,enumerate(self.arr_a))

        print(self.link)

def task():

    obj=class_a()
    obj.func_a()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    task()


Normal objects are not shared or synchronized between processes. Use the return value or the special objects from the multiprocessing package to send data back to the main process.

When using multiprocessing, objects are not shared across the main process and workers  - rather, each argument passed as a parameter to a function that will run in the worker (through, for example, the Poll.map call), is serialized - i.e. converted to a byte-stream representation, and de-serialized in the worker process. If one simply uses the multiprocessing.Process(target=...).start() approach, even the return value of the called function is ignored.
When using Pool.map, though, Python arranges it so the return values on the target workers are serialized and sent back to the originating process, in a transparent way.
So, if you simply change your in-subprocess methods to return the results of their calculations, instead of trying to access these results in place, your code would work.
However, for this specific workload, you want to each time the remote-function is called, it tries to work on data already existing and created by peer procecess: the self.link list will exist independently in each process - and if a key is created in worker 1  it will not exist in worker[2]  - and a new instance of class_b would be created.
For cases where this is unavoidable, Python´s stdlib provide the "Manager" classes - which will allow a list-proxy object to behave as it is shared across each worker (in practice, when a worker access an object in the list, it is implicitly serialized - a deserialized in that object - in your case, a new instance of class_b would be created in worker[2] if worker1 would put it on the list, and there are complications do keep it in sync unless one KNOW what they are doing very well. (for example, the same list item has to be updated back with the retrieved class_b instance, otherwise the Manager won´t be able to know it has changed in worker[2]. and for another example: there would be race-conditions: if worker[2] and worker[3]  retrieve a class_b instance at the same time, whoever updates it back last "wins" - and the way to fix that is using Locks  - the code gets a lot more complicated).
It will be good for you to experience with multiprocessing.Manager and do some trial and error to get the ways it works - specially if this code represents a real-world use case you would have. In this answer, however, I am not exploring that path, and opting for a simpler option, less prone to complicated edge-cases.
All that said, the ideal approach when using concurrency is trying to architect your algorithms so that each worker can do its job in an independent way - for your workload, consolidating the several class_b instances in the main process might be the easiest.
Perceive that even though the work of consolidating all the results may not be trivial (and your example code happens to have some particularities that have to be considered), this approach is still safer than using the "manager" based one.

class class_b:
     
     def __init__(self):
          
        self.counter=0
        self.sum=[]

@classmethod
def consolidate(cls, instances: "iterable[class_b]"):
    self = cls()  # creates an empty "class_b"
    dropped_first = False
    for instance in instances:
        #  to preserve the behavior of your original code,
        # of an instance not getting a new number in "sum"
        # when it is first created, I will frop a "counter" 
        # number, and the first number for the first processed instance
        if not dropped_first:
            instance.counter -= 1
            instance.sum.pop(0)
            dropped_first = True
        self.counter += instance.counter
        self.sum.extend(instance.sum)
    
    return self

class class_a:

    import random as ran
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import os

    def __init__(self):

        self.link=[0]*50
        self.arr_a=[0]*100

    def func_b(self,arg):
        
        arr_key=self.ran.randint(0, 50)

        if self.link[arr_key] ==0:

            self.link[arr_key]=class_b()

        # here I modify your code: in the original the first 
        # time an item is reached, it doesn't get a new "sum" number:
        # I create one each time, and this first 
        # number is discarded when consolidating the results
        obj=self.link[arr_key]
        obj.counter+=1
        obj.sum.append(self.ran.randint(0,10))
    
        print(self.link)
        return self.link  # return the list local for this process.

        

    def func_a(self):
        
        with self.Pool(processes=self.os.cpu_count()) as pool:

            all_results = pool.map(self.func_b,enumerate(self.arr_a))
        new_links = []
        for items_at_index in zip(all_results):
            # in each interation "item_at_index" will have a slice
            # of all returned "link" lists for that index (that is what `zip` does)
            items_with_results = [item for item in items_at_index if item is not 0]
            if items_with_results:
                new_links.append(class_b.consolidate(items_with_results))
            else:
                new_links.append(0)

        self.link = new_links

        print(self.link)

def task():

    obj=class_a()
    obj.func_a()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    task()






I finally decided not to use shared memory, and therefore I don't need the subcalculated stuff. Thanks for the great answer.
